# What does it mean to find a symmetry which induces the transposition $(1,2)$ of the vertices of a Tetrahedron?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I get that this would mean we would just switch the $1$ and $2$ vertices, but how is it a symmetry that way? What happens to vertices $3$ and $4$?

This is on a tetrahedron where the top vertex is $1$, and then from left to right, the vertices are labeled $2,3,4$.

[image]

Comment: Consider a plane of mirror symmetry defined by two vertices and the mid-point of the opposite edge.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

This type of symmetry is sometimes known as a *reflection*. Imagine a mirror in the plane through the line between points $3$ & $4$ and through the midpoint of the line through $1$ & $2$.

The vertices $3$ & $4$ are left fixed by the symmetry in the mirror, whereas, as required, $1$ & $2$ are swapped.